# Rails - Save another Model's object on before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Can I call a "save" to an object of model A inside the "before_save" callback of another model B?

the case: I have an Event model which has Artists. When I'm saving an Event I need to associate it with those artists and, if the Artist still doesn't exist, I need to create it and save it. (Just a string is passed, not the Object, that's why he can not exist on Event-creation time)

So, the question is: can I call an artist.save on the Event's before_save?

A controversial comment was posted here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_save but the "observed sometimes" is really scaring.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to prove a negative, but a quick scan through the open tickets in [Lighthouse](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets?q=before_save%20state%3aopen&filter=) doesn't show anything related to the comment you found.

In general though, you might want to push the Artist assignment/save up the chain a bit to the `before_validation` callback.  That way, you can require the Artist in the Event model and catch any issues with Artist creation in the Event validations.